# TCP communication with robotic arm -Destination Host Unreachable-

Tags: networking, matlab, ip, arm, tcp-ip

I'm trying to communicate with a robotic arm via TCP/IP communcation. It works well on windows but when i try it on linux matlab i cannot connect to arm. Matlab tries to connect again and again

```
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
```

and when i ping i get

```
PING 169.254.131.130 (169.254.131.130) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 169.254.131.130 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, +12 errors, 100% packet loss, time 12055ms
pipe 3
```

The problem might be linux ip settings. What do you suggest?

Comment: This question is a cross-post of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39269647/3585386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 169.254.x.x is not a valid IP range per se. Means windows box tried to get an IP via DHCP failes and just picked a random one from that range. Assign a correct ip in the same subnet as 192.168.2.4 and you should be good

Comment: what if the machines ip adress is fixed and i cant change it? is there any solution for this situation?

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. You just need to edit wired network as shared to other computers from automatic to connect devices such mine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)